# How to access shapekey driver via Python?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers, shape-keys

I can access the shapekeys of an object like:

```
bpy.data.objects['mesh'].data.shape_keys.key_blocks
```

And I can get the "shapekeys package" of the object with:

```
bpy.data.objects['mesh'].data.shape_keys.name
```

I can access the drivers from that "shapekeys package":

```
bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.002'].animation_data.drivers.items()
```

I need to **check scripted expressions and variables from drivers**. The access could be this way:

```
bpy.data.shape_keys[bpy.data.objects['mesh'].data.shape_keys.name].animation_data.drivers.items()
```

Would be this the best way (more short) to access this info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All shape keys are stored in `bpy.data.shape_keys` and can be applied to multiple objects. Each object possesses an attribute pointing to the shape key if it is using any. Thus

```
shape_key = bpy.data.objects['yourObject'].data.shape_keys
```

will give you access to it directly.

`bpy.data.shape_keys` is a `bpy_prop_collection` which allows access to its elements by name or index.

So if you know the index or the name of a shape key you will probably want to access it from `bpy.data.shape_keys`.

If you don't know which shape key is used by an object you will retrieve it from `obj.data.shape_keys`.

### Expression & Variables:

```
# Access by index only
driver = bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.002'].animation_data.drivers[index]
driver.driver.expression
driver.driver.variables
```

Comment: Then access to drivers only can be made by index, right?

Comment: Yes. Pass an integer. The `keys()` method which is supposed to return the available string keys of the elements in the collection always returns an empty list `[]` for drivers.

Comment: It's the same for `Object.animation_data.action.fcurves.keys()`, and it's not even a bug. There's simply no name, only `data_path` and `array_index`, which sort of identifies a Driver/FCurve. But it's possible to have both properties set to the same values, although only the one with the highest index number (bottom-most channel in F-Curve Editor) is apparantly evaluated (even for delta-transforms). Hence, you need to either use the index, or loop over all `.fcurves` or `.drivers`, check the `data_path` and `array_index` values and pick the one you are after.

Comment: I'm accesing now to drivers name via "data_path". Well, thanks to everyone about this!